# Как удалить все символы кроме цифр в notepad++?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Как удалить все символы кроме цифр в notepad++? Нужны регулярные выражения?

Пример:

> `"": ",,-, ,,❤\\ :\  ( ) +380958795928",`

Comment: Вы не поверите `/[^\d]/`

Comment: Не работает в notepad+

Comment: @CruzeFan, уберите слеши и все заработает - `[^\d]`

Comment: да, теперь работает, но я не учел что теперь все номера слились в одни цифры а не по строкам...

Comment: А разве `+` не нужен?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, регулярные выражения нужны.

Из меню выберите:

`Поиск | Замена...` (или просто <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)

- Режим поиска: `Регуляр. выражен.`
- Найти: `\D`
- Заменить на: (пустое - не пишите ничего)

Регулярное выражение `\D` значит: "всякий символ кроме цифры". Все такие знаки будут заменены *пустыми символами*, т.е. они исчезнут.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

`[^\d\s]`

Представление `\s` является сокращённой версией всех  whitespace символов `[ \t\n\r\f\v]`

Тогда у вас сохранятся пробелы, табуляции, переходы на новую строку, etc.

Comment: Вы уверены насчет `\S`? Вы проверили?

Comment: Извиняюсь, имел в виду `\s`. Исправил ответ

Comment: Так лучше. Еще лучше - `[\D\S]`. То есть,  обратное и на один знак меньше. Но это на ваше усмотрение.

Answer (score 0):

`\D` - все кроме цифр. Проверить https://regex101.com/r/mTIbIB/1

Comment: является ) достаточно открыть notepad++ и проверить. если вы модератор этого раздела поступайте с ответом как считаете нужным.

Comment: пускай так, но  будьте добры, дайте ответ полный и понятный